# Switching the update channel on Firefox Flame fails

Tags: firefox-os

I tried to follow the steps to change the update channel described here: [Switch to nightly update channel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox_OS/Developer_phone_guide/Flame#Switch_to_nightly_update_channel). But the phone won't reboot after executing change_channel.sh because the scripts fails with

```
$ ./change_channel.sh -v aurora
adbd is already running as root
remount succeeded
cannot stat '/tmp/channel-prefs/updates.js': No such file or directory
```

Currently I have B2G 21.0.0.0-prerelease installed from [here](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/b2g/nightly/2014-11-06-16-12-14-mozilla-b2g34_v2_1-flame-kk/).

Answer (score 0):

I you open the script and read the line 57, there is

```
cat >$TMP_DIR/updates.js <<UPDATES
```

If it fails to create the file in that directory, he won't be able to push it when doing adb push:

```
$ADB push $TMP_DIR/updates.js $B2G_PREF_DIR/updates.js
```

So check your permissions or change the temp directory to let your script create the updates.js file,

```
TMP_DIR=/tmp/channel-prefs
```